# Show on no selection

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Have a div to show when option "choose an option" is selected. 
By default "choose an option" is the option that is selected on a page load.

I know I need to use the .show but I am not sure how to get it to work specifically when there are two options available and either of them has the choose an option selected.

an example when a product has two selections size and colour I need the Div to show until both selections are not "choose an option"

I would like to use Jquery with woocommerce variable products. 
I have used table variations to hide the variable price table but I would like it to show again if "choose an Option" is selected.

```
jQuery('table.variations select').on('change', function() {

  jQuery('.vanish ').hide();

} );
```

```html
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_quantity">Quantity</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_quantity" class="" name="attribute_pa_quantity" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_quantity" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="each" class="attached enabled">Each</option>
          <option value="pck-10" class="attached enabled">PCK/10</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_color">Colour</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="blue" class="attached enabled">Blue</option>
          <option value="red" class="attached enabled">Red</option>
          <option value="white" class="attached enabled">White</option>
          <option value="yellow" class="attached enabled">Yellow</option>
        </select><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">Clear</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The goal is to show a div whenever the option"choose an option" is selected and hide it when any other option is selected

Comment: can you also add other div structure which you want to hide and show?

Comment: Sorry , I have already answered your question what I read first time. Also you have to do some stuff at your end too. This platform is not meant for `please give me full code`. You have to try things at your end, and if not work then you have to ask **new question**, not to rewrite original question, because re-writing original question make all answers irrelevant.

Comment: Sir I appreciate your input but I simply clarified the original question. Your answer was great and I appreciate your input. If you would like to input on this I would very much appreciate it especially since I didn't understand how you got it to work. I tried reversing your code by removing the! So it only happened when= to choose. I also took out the hide to ensure that the div shown on page load. If you can help I would appreciate it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your question and provided code i have assumed that you need to hide  if choose option is not selected , or if other than choose option is selected you need to hide certain div.

please write if this is what you wanted check below i have written some answers that may help

html part /select option

```js
$('.select').on('change', function() { //on change function on select option 

  value = $(this).val(); //take value from options


  if (value != 'choose') { //if value is not choose than hide
    $('#div_use').css('display', 'None'); //hiding div
  }else{
     $('#div_use').css('display', ''); //show div again 
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <!-- select option -->
        <select class="select">
           
            <option value ="choose">choose option</option>
            <option value ="test1">This is an option1</option>
            <option value ="test2">This is an option2</option>
           
        </select>
    </div>
<div id='div_use'>not selected<div> <!-- div to hide -->
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the issue I am still facing is when choose option is selected again not selected is not showing again. How should I refine the question to reflect this?

Comment: hey i have edited ,my answer is that what u needed?

Comment: Yeah, that is great, Thank you. Do you know how I use an if any value ="choose", I am guessing it is a derivative of .val   I have tried working with a Var and setting the .val property, I also inverted the if statement? That way if it met the criteria it would show and if not it would hide.

Let me know if I have to create a new Question as I am new to the forum and have looked into the .val  documentation but I can not seem to find a val of any element instead of the first.

please let me know how to improve my question I really appreciate your time

Comment: you can create new question with sample code and what you want to do must be clear so others can help